# how to send a single element from browser to server without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vxworks

How can I send just one element from browser to server fast and without reloading browser page?

Is there an AJAX way to do this, that is a NON-FILE method?  The opposite of ".load"?

.load works great sending a single element from server to browser without page reload.
How to do the opposite direction?

Browser is JavaScript.
Server is vxworks with windmarks.

PRESENT METHOD THAT WORKS BUT RELOADS PAGE:
Presently, the browser element is  and I use submit to send it to the server, but this takes too long and reloads the browser page.

The element's innerHTML contains data formatted as a vxworks WINDMARK.
(When the vxworks server receives this submission, it reads the windmark and copies it to a 'C' string for backend software to process.)

Comment: You can send data with http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and send data using `jQuery`. using something like this:

```
$.post('urlfromserver',browserdata,function(datafromserver){
    //do stuff
})
```

if you let me put a little bit more, it's a good idea to use [JSON](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to send/receive data to/from server. Having that in mind, you can do something like:

```
$.post('urlfromserver',{browserdata: JSON.stringify(browserdata)},function(datafromserver){
    javascriptObject = jQuery.parseJSON(datafromserver)
    //do stuff
})
```

And in your PHP code, it would be as simple as using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) to send data to `javascript` and `json_decode` to receive data from `javascript`

**UPDATE**

Obtaining the data in the server should be as simple as requesting the object via post or get depending on your send method, and parsing the JSON.

In `PHP`, this is an example of obtaining data using the above code:

```
  $dataFromBrowser = json_decode($_POST['browserdata'])
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get 'browserdata' to be written to a specific element of the server page?
(I'm not using PHP.  But by the end of this project, I might need a little PCP.   :-)

Comment: This worked.  Here is my solution code, which writes to a vxworks windmark on the vxworks web server:

$.post('','general_page_to_MM_data_1_windmark=fffffffffffffff',function(datafromserver){ //do stuff })

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery and PHP then something like this should work:

JS:

```
$.ajax('doServerSuff.php?action1=saveLog', function() { 
    // do stuff after server received the data
});
```

PHP (doServerStuff.php):

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['action1'] == 'saveLog') {
        //do stuff
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.post` in jQuery to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

The load intruction can also be used to transmit data to the server:

```
$().load("url", {limit: 25}, function(){
    //transmission finished
});
```

In this example the parameter limit with the value 25 wil be transmitted to the server.
Taken from:http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get the transmit data to replace a specific element, by 'id', down in the server?  I know the server element's id.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do with the ajax call like this**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "yourpage.php?id=someValue",
               success:function(data){
               //do some stuff here
            });
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, if 'data' gets written to id 'someValue'.   I will try it, and report result...

Comment: What is the 'data' argument to the function for?

Comment: 'data' is what comes back from server.

NOTE: 2nd closing '}' is missing.

QUESTION:  how can I get it to do the same page without specifying the page ('yourpage.php')?

Comment: Thanks!  I got it working.
NOTE:  If 'yourpage.php' is omitted, then it uses the same page.

Comment: But, the success function does not fire:

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "?general_page_to_MM_data_1_windmark=DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", 
      success:function(data_from_server){ 
    alert('FROM SERVER: ' + data_from_server )
   }});

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  Here is the corrected JavaScript, from the above answer.

Here is how to change a single element at the server.

This is also an example of how to write to a vxworks windmark string at a vxworks web server, without reloading the page.

NOTE:  no URL is specified, so that the same page is used.

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "?general_page_to_MM_data_1_windmark=CCCCCCCCCCCCCC", 
        success:function(data_from_server){ 
    }});
```